# Set the default value of a float to NaN?

Tags: c#

When creating a float, it has the default value of zero. However, I want it to default to NaN because the value should be unknown, or in other words, it should indicate that no value has yet been assigned to it. I will later assign values, where possible, and where not possible, the property should be left as NaN because no value could be found for it. Therefore, NaN is the appropriate starting state. So, this is what I've done:

```
class SmallObject
{
    public float A { get; set; } = float.NaN; // slow, but the value is NaN, which is correct
    public float B { get; set; } = float.NaN; // slow, but the value is NaN, which is correct
    public float C { get; set; } = float.NaN; // slow, but the value is NaN, which is correct
    public float D { get; set; } = float.NaN; // slow, but the value is NaN, which is correct
    public float E { get; set; } = float.NaN; // slow, but the value is NaN, which is correct
}
```

All properties are initialized with float.NaN, but the problem is, this is very slow, because the properties are initialized with a value, and I'm creating millions of SmallObject. Below is much faster, but the property values are zero:

```
class SmallObject
{
    public float A { get; set; } // fast, but the value is zero, which is wrong
    public float B { get; set; } // fast, but the value is zero, which is wrong
    public float C { get; set; } // fast, but the value is zero, which is wrong
    public float D { get; set; } // fast, but the value is zero, which is wrong
    public float E { get; set; } // fast, but the value is zero, which is wrong
}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
class SmallObject
{
    public myFloat A { get; set; } // fast, and the value is NaN, which is correct
    public myFloat B { get; set; } // fast, and the value is NaN, which is correct
    public myFloat C { get; set; } // fast, and the value is NaN, which is correct
    public myFloat D { get; set; } // fast, and the value is NaN, which is correct
    public myFloat E { get; set; } // fast, and the value is NaN, which is correct
}
```

Here, myFloat is a custom float which defaults to NaN, without any overhead, so it runs just as fast as a normal float that defaults to zero. Is this, or something like it, possible? Thanks.

**Update**

Due to feedback from the comments, I've decided to provide measurements to back up my claim that initializing a float with a value is slower than leaving it alone.

Creating 10 million SmallObject with 5 properties of float:

- Release 32 bit: 32 ms
- Release 64 bit: 4 ms

Creating 10 million SmallObject with 5 properties of float initialized to float.NaN:

- Release 32 bit: 44 ms
- Release 64 bit: 53 ms

Creating 10 million SmallObject with 5 properties of float?:

- Release 32 bit: 43 ms
- Release 64 bit: 4 ms

All results are median values. As you can see, initializing a float to NaN is a whopping **13.25 times** slower than leaving it unintialized for 64 bit release. In conclusion, for 64 bit release, float? is the best option when it comes to creating objects. However, I've noticed that downstream, float? might cause  problems due to having to often convert it to a regular float for calculations (eg. Math.Abs and Math.Log as well as BitConverter).

Comment: What is your proof for your claim that "this is very slow"?

Comment: Why not use a nullable float?  `public float? A {get;set;}`

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Because it's slower to initialize properties with a value than to leave them as default.

Comment: There is no mechanism for changing the way default-initialization works.

Comment: For me the real question would be: Why are you creating millions of public `properties` that you might not ever need?

Comment: Using BitConverter you will find NAN is {0x00, 0x00, 0xC0, 0xFF}  So it may be quicker to create an array of floats and copy the bytes to memory.  Would be very easy in c++.

Comment: Using float? would probably be what you are looking for. I argue that there is some confusion of how C# and VB.NET are working. The point of @Barns is also true. What you try to achieve with millions of properties sounds unsexy :)

Comment: _Because it's slower to initialize properties with a value than to leave them as default._ That is what you believe. Can you prove it? In both cases a bit pattern must be set in memory. Once. Why bother??? Goggle 'premature optimization !

Comment: If you really want to, I suppose you could do:
`private bool _isAssignedA;
 private float _a;
 public float A { 
  get { return _isAssignedA ? _a : float.NaN; }
  set { _a = value; _isAssignedA = true; } 
 }`

This would avoid the need to assign the floats to NaN at instantiation. That said, using float? seems to be the best option. Unlike NaN, null is intended to represent an unassigned value.

Comment: Also, with regards to "Because it's slower to initialize properties with a value than to leave them as default," have you actually tried measuring the difference?

Comment: I just tried instantiating 1,000,000,000 (1 billion) instances each. With the default assignment, it took my computer 11.711 seconds, with the extra float.NaN assignment, it took 14.635 seconds. So it seems like there is a slight difference of about 25%. But, this would only matter if we are talking about a really extreme number of instances.

Comment: You don't get to change the way the CLR works.  Whenever you have perf issues with a "small class", the first thing you'd consider is to make it a struct.  Not quite small enough, so next you'd see if the recent C# ref/in syntax changes can get you ahead.

Comment: @jdweng that's just one of the possible bit patterns for NaN

Comment: Ran some benchmarks. No NaN assignment: 1.185s average (0.0094s standard deviation) on a method creating 10,000,000 instances. NaN assignment: 1.199s average (0.0055s standard deviation). Percentage difference: 1.17%. [Benchmark code](https://pastebin.com/GUPy8PnL) - I used BenchmarkDotNet, .NET Core 2.2, and ran it in Release mode without the debugger. My question now is: is this something you really need to optimise?

Comment: I know, but it is the one the library uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a nullable float. Nullable types were introduced in C# 2.0.

```
float? myNullableFloat;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
private float foo = Single.NaN;
public float Foo { get => foo; set => foo = value; }
```